# libc6 package Breaks openssh-server - how do I get it back?

Tags: debian, apt

On my Debian Jessie server I had testing repositories enabled for some reason and I ran an upgrade recently that removed the openssh-server package.

I am assuming this happened because of a [recent glibc bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=965932) which made it so the libc6 package now has a Breaks: openssh-server tag on it.

As I mentioned, running the upgrade removed the ssh package, and now I am completely unable to install it again.

What should I do about this? Is there another bugfix incoming? Should I try to install an even newer version of OpenSSH on this Jessie machine? Is it somehow possible to downgrade libc6?

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian . I wouldn't upgrade libc6. Instead I would recompile from (Debian) source a package not available in jessie, using jessie's build tools and glibc.

Comment: Jessie is past its LTS lifetime anyway. It's long past time to upgrade.